# iOS Saving Entire Core Data DB to JSON string and vice versa

Tags: iphone, ios, json, ipad, core-data

Im wondering how I go about serializing the entire core database on an iOS app to JSON so I can back it up in the cloud. Than when the user wants to restore how to go about taking the JSON string back and generating an entire core database from that?

Is it possible? Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can easily use  `NSJSONSerialization`  to serialize/deserialize objects to/from JSON, and  `NSURLRequest/Connection`  to upload or download JSON.

`AFNetworking`  is a popular networking framework that has JSON serialization/deserialization built in. I have not used it yet so I cannot vouch for it personally, but it looks quite functional.

`NSManagedObject`  (the Core Data base object) has an  `NSEntityDescription`  associated with it, which has the method  `- (NSDictionary *)attributesByName` , which should make it easy to write serialization/deserialization methods without having to write explicit code for every class and attribute.

I find Core Data to be heavy and complex for most of my needs and typically write local storage and serialization/deserialization using the  `NSCoding`  protocol. You might look into that as well for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Putting the JSON into Core Data definitely can be done but it takes a custom function that puts all the data in the proper place. `JSONObjectWithData` will take a JSON file and put it into an NSDictionary.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://linktojson.com/file.json"]];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:data
                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                 error:&error];
```

From there you can put the data from the dictionary into Core Data.

For the other way around, it can probably be done and `dataWithJSONObject` will probably be the final step but getting there will probably be along the lines of reconstructing the NSDictionary that `JSONObjectWithData` created above.